# Alternative Java Methods for Encoding String to Base64

Tags: java, c#, base64, encode

In C#, I can pass a string to `Convert.FromBase64String(String string)`, which returns a `byte[]`. Take, for example, the following code:

```
string key = "lRixPxNRmNOTxB2npoa5zCZR2I/GkuCndWtcRS/w4CI=";
byte[] KeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
Console.WriteLine(KeyBytes.Length); //output 32
```

If I try the same thing in java using the `java.util.Base64` library,
it looks something like this:

```
String key = "lRixPxNRmNOTxB2npoa5zCZR2I/GkuCndWtcRS/w4CI=";
byte[] base64KeyBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(key.getBytes(UTF_8));
System.out.println(base64KeyBytes.length); //output 60
```

The Java `encode` method requires a type `byte[]` for the argument, and I think this is what my problem stems from.

Is there anyway a way in Java to produce the same output that I'm getting in C#?

Comment: Surely you want to **decode** here?

Comment: Maybe .net version uses platform default encoding that is different than utf-8 such as iso-8859.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `Convert.FromBase64String` in `.NET` is used for **decoding** base64-encoded strings back to plain text. And this is correct since your `key` string is base64-encoded.

In your `Java` code excerpt, on the opposite, you are attempting to **encode** your already-base64-encoded string using the `encode` method... when you should instead **decode** it. In order to do it, use the following code:

```
String key = "lRixPxNRmNOTxB2npoa5zCZR2I/GkuCndWtcRS/w4CI=";
byte[] base64KeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(key);
System.out.println(base64KeyBytes.length); // 32
```

You can alternatively use `android.util.base64` as follows:

```
String key = "lRixPxNRmNOTxB2npoa5zCZR2I/GkuCndWtcRS/w4CI=";
byte[] base64KeyBytes = Base64.decode(key, Base64.DEFAULT);
System.out.println(base64KeyBytes.length); // 32
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `decode` not `encode`

```
  String key = "lRixPxNRmNOTxB2npoa5zCZR2I/GkuCndWtcRS/w4CI=";
  byte[] base64KeyBytes  = Base64.getDecoder().decode(key);
  System.out.println(base64KeyBytes .length); //output 32
```